# Getting Facebook Profile URL from Facebook App-scoped id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I just learned that starting with the Facebook API 2.0 , users registering with apps will get a unique facebook id specific to that app.
In my application, I need the user's profile url. The response I get from calling the graph's "/me" path looks like this:
https://facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app_scoped_user_id}

But this will not take me to the user's profile unless I am logged in. Whereas using the real facebook id will take me to the public profile regardless of my logged-in state.

**My question is: How to get the public user profile url from the app-scoped facebook id, or how to get the real facebook user id from the app-scoped id?**

Thanks.

Comment: This is no longer possible with Graph API v2.0

Comment: There has to be a way or a hack, no?

Comment: If there's a illegal hack solution, this answer will be downvote by Facebook enginnering team and reply "It's violate TOS of this platform". If there's a legal hack solution, this answer/bug will be fix by them soon.  So, no point you asking hack solution here.

Comment: it's really ironic facebook made up AppLink but not allowing 'deep' linking to user's facebook profile page anymore. :-/